# Error while running behat

Tags: php, testing, behat

The first scenario works but the second one fails

The feature file:

```
And I click the "#redeem" element
And I wait for the ajax response
And I should see "OPERATOR CONTACT DETAILS AND INFORMATION WILL BE PROVIDED VIA EMAIL ON CONFIRMATION"
And I click the "#place_order" element
And I wait for the ajax response
Then I should see "Woohoo and thanks for booking!"

@javascript
Scenario: For checking mail in inbox of Gmail 
Given I am on "https://gmail.com"
And I wait 12 seconds
And I fill in "Email" with "amit.dinda.prdxn@gmail.com"
```

the minkcontext:

```
/**
     * Fills in form field with specified id|name|label|value.
     *
     * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
     * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with:$/
     * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" for "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
     */
    public function fillField($field, $value)
    {
        $field = $this->fixStepArgument($field);
        $value = $this->fixStepArgument($value);
        $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($field, $value);
    }
```

The error message :

```
 And I should see "OPERATOR CONTACT DETAILS AND INFORMATION WILL BE PROVIDED VIA EMAIL ON CONFIRMATION" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    And I click the "#place_order" element                                                                 # FeatureContext::iClickTheElement()
    And I wait for the ajax response                                                                       # FeatureContext::iWaitForTheAjaxResponse()
    Then I should see "Woohoo and thanks for booking!"                                                     # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()

  @javascript
  Scenario: For checking mail in inbox of Gmail                                 # features/Redeem_a_Experience_voucher.feature:45
    Given I am on "https://gmail.com"                                           # FeatureContext::visit()
    And I wait 12 seconds                                                       # FeatureContext::iWaitSeconds()
    And I fill in "Email" with "amit.dinda.prdxn@gmail.com"                     # FeatureContext::fillField()
      Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "Email" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
    And I click the "#next" element
```

And if run both scenario differently then it works porperly. Why it not work if both scenario are combined together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@insulated` tag at the Feature level.
This tag will make sure that you will have a clean session each time.

Add this tag on the first line of your feature file, before `Feature` key.

> You can use @javascript the same way at a feature level and it will apply for each scenario

Comment: Is there any possibility to copy a particular text from gmail and use that in my next scenario?

Comment: Yes, save it in a class variable.If you are using in different context then save it in FeatureContext or create an new class that will handle the data.